# Transform a conceptual schema into a collection of relational schema

Tags: mysql

I want to transform a conceptual schema given in a linked file into a collection of relational schemas. For each relational schema create lists the names of:

- Attributes
- Primary Key
- Candidate keys (if any)
- Foreign keys (if any)

Assume, that partitioning method must be used to implement a generalization.

[image]

Please help to solve this question. Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you tried and where are the difficulties. SO is not a code-writing service. Welcome aboard.

Comment: i want  transform the linked image into following format Staff( Staffno, SName, DOB, SLevel, DName)
Primary key = (Staffno)
Foreign key =(DName) references Department (DName)
Department(DName, MainOffice, Headerno)
Primary key = (DName),
Foreign key = (Headerno) references Staff(Staffno)


Project (Pn, Sponsor, StartDate, EndDate, Budget,
Managerno)
Primary key = (Pno)
Foreign key = (Managerno) references Staff (Staffno)
Device (ID, System, WiFi, Pno)
Primary key = (ID)
Foreign key = (Pno) references Project(Pno)